# Documenting included header files in .c files with Doxygen comments?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have noticed, that when using Doxygen to document a .c file, the list of includes in the given file is also included in the output, for instance:

https://agnix.sourceforge.net/documentation/api/bridge_8c.html

[image: bridge_c_doxygen_page]

Now, what I typically do, is include some general comments before a given "include block" ("intro comments"), and then some specific comments on the same line as the include line:

```c
...
/*
* The following includes are required for 
* the code to compile:
*/

#include <stdio.h> // contains printf()
#include <netinet/in.h> // contains sockaddr_in
...
```

Is it possible to have these kinds of comments formatted for Doxygen, (either "intro comments", or "on same line" - hopefully both), such that I get them output in the final documentation for that .C file?

Essentially, for the above example, I'd get an output like this (screenshot is from manually hacked HTML, to get a mock-up of desired output):

[image: bridge_c_doxygen_hacked]

(I guess, this could be seen as a somewhat of a "literal programming" approach)

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What you want to accomplish, commenting about an included include file line, is not supported by doxygen

Comment: Thanks @albert - good to know explicitly that what I want to do is not supported; otherwise I have doxygen  1.9.5

Answer (score 1):

If you want Doxygen recognizes a file to insert it in documentation, you should use

```
/** <- (this format is recognized by Doxygen)
 * @file    name_of_file.h
 * 
 * @brief   What is
 * 
 * @author  You
 * 
 * @date    03/01/2023
 * 
 * @par     Put the title of the paragraph
 * Write the content of the paragraph
 */
```

at the beginning of your header file (note: @file is mandatory).

Read also [Doxygen guide](https://embeddedinventor.com/guide-to-configure-doxygen-to-document-c-source-code-for-beginners/)

Comment: Thanks @Filippo, I guess my question was not clear, so I edited it - I do not merely want to recognize a file, I want to output documentation text where a comment placed before the include block in code, maps to text placed before the include block in the documentation page; please see edited question